# Storing the class name in class variable without typing the name of the class?

Tags: python, class, classname

In an instance method of a python class, I know that we can get the class name via `self.__class__.__name__`

However, I'd like to store the name of a class in a class variable, without coding the name of the class.

I know I can do this to get a class's name into a class variable:

```
class MyClass(object):
  pass
MyClass._myname = MyClass.__name__
```

However, I have to code the string `MyClass` two times outside of the class definition, simply to get the class name into a class variable. In this case, that would be `"MyClass"`, which I could simply code as follows:

```
class MyClass(object):
  _myname = "MyClass"
```

But even that is redundant, given that I have to hard-code `"MyClass"` within the `MyClass` class.

What I'd like is to somehow get a class's name into a class variable without coding the class's name, as follows:

```
class MyClass(object):
  _myname = ???? # where ???? is a statement which returns the class
                 # name, in which the string "MyClass" does not appear
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a decorator

```
>>> def autoname(cls):
...    cls._MyName=cls.__name__
...    return cls
... 
>>> @autoname
... class check:
...    pass
... 
>>> check._MyName
'check'
>>>
```

Or if you do not want to hard-code the name of the attribute:

```
>>> def autoname2(name):
...     def autoname(cls):
...         setattr(cls, name, cls.__name__)
...         return cls
...     return autoname
...
>>> @autoname2('_StoreHere')
... class check2:
...     pass
... 
>>> check2._StoreHere
'check2'
>>>
```

Of course, the second form can take more parameters, for example:

```
>>> def autoname3(name, f=lambda x: x):
...     def autoname(cls):
...         setattr(cls, name, f(cls.__name__))
...         return cls
...     return autoname
...
>>> @autoname3('_MyNameIs', lambda x: x.upper() + '_The_Bold')
... class check3:
...     pass
... 
>>> check3._MyNameIs
'CHECK3_The_Bold'
>>>
```

A note on decorator vs metaclass: Metaclasses are seriously cool, nonetheless, if one doesn't strictly need them they are better avoided because of the infamous [metaclass conflicts](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/#reduced-chance-of-metaclass-conflicts).

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with a metaclass:

```
class NameMeta(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        dct['_name'] = name
        return super().__new__(meta, name, bases, dct)

class Foo(metaclass=NameMeta):
    pass

print(Foo._name)     # prints "Foo"
```

Do note that setting the name as a new attribute on the class is a bit silly, since `__name__` already exists. Probably you should change whatever code you are writing that looks at the `_name` attribute and make it look for `__name__` instead.

Comment: Well, actually, I over-simplified the problem. What I really want is for the class variable to contain some data which is dependent on the class name ... in other words, it would be the result of a function of the class name.

Comment: PS: Can a question have two answers flagged? The answer from Bickkngt and the answer from Paul Panzer both give me the info I am looking for. I would like to flag both of your answers, if possible.

Comment: @HippoMan You can upvote both. But accept I'm pretty sure you can only one.

Comment: OK. I like both answers equally, and I have now just arbitrarily accepted the first one. Thanks again to both of you.